# how to delete a row in Android sqlite where date range is not matched

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I Have a Table like this

```
        Date                    value
 2014-4-15 14:22:33               A
 2014-4-15 13:55:7                B
 2014-4-15 14:54:33               C
 2014-4-15 15:11:36               D
 2014-4-15 15:22:21               E
```

how to write a Query to delete rows which does not match the date and time range my range is "2014-4-15 15:00:00" to current time say "2014-4-15 15:30:00". After deleting rows ,my table should look like this

```
       Date                    value
 2014-4-15 15:11:36               D
 2014-4-15 15:22:21               E
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why aren't your datetime fields zero padded? Things get so much easier when you zero pad them, e.g. `04` instead of `4`, `07` instead of `7`.

Comment: delete from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_NAME NOT BETWEEN "START_VALUE" AND "END_VALUE"

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from TABLE where DATE < '2014-4-15 15:00:00' or DATE > '2014-4-15 15:30:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE NOT BETWEEN "2014-4-15 15:00:00" AND "2014-4-15 15:30:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATE <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND 
DATE >= datetime('2014-4-15 15:30:00');
```

or for delete:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATE >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND 
DATE <= datetime('2014-4-15 15:30:00');
```